# How can I insert tcov to Make File

Tags: code-coverage, solaris

How can i use tcov on Solaris in make file? My make file makes .o files and then the .so files which is copying to the lib's folder. I work with Oracle BRM

```html
CFLAGS_solaris= -g -xcg92 -xprofile=tcov

C++FLAGS_solaris= -g -library=%none -DPIN_NOT_USING_OSTREAM 

CPPFLAGS = -I$(INCDIR) -I$(INCDIR_MDS) -DPCMCPP_CONST_SAFE 

LDFLAGS_solaris= -G

SL_EXT_solaris= so
```

and i tried also:

```html
 this makes the .so file;
$(LIBBILL): $(OBJECTS) $(C++_OBJECTS) $(INCFILES) Makefile
 $(C++) -o $(LIBBILL) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(C++_OBJECTS) -lm -lpsiu_for_cm -xprofile=tcov 
    
   
and this makes the .o files
$(OBJECTS): $(INCFILES) Makefile $(FILES)
 $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)  $(FILES)
```

the result of that is the brm can't start.

Comment: What kind of error message(s) are you getting.  Saying "brm can't start" doesn't provide any usable information.

Comment: sorry, my bad. brm couldn't start due to lack of memory. brm starts normally now and everything goes well. I have other issue now. How can I use tcov with ld instead of cc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is looking for an answer I found the solution. You have to use 
-xprofile=tcov while compiling .o files and also when you links .so file ;)